# What's the best way ro read from a config file in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I know this can be a lot subjective. I always worked with frameworks so I am a bit lost when I have to work on something from scratch.

I want to make a class that reads values from a config file. I'd prefer to use a php array as a config file rather than a .ini one.

What's the best approach for that? using require_once inside a method looks to me a bit odd.

what I would like to do is a class that reads a config file and exposes this values as properties...

thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Updated answer with no **ini** version

Comment: you *know* the question is subjective, yet you still ask it, even if that's explicitely off-topic?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann many thanks for your constructive attitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read any ini file in to array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
print_r($ini_array);
```

To use an **array** through require(require_once):

```
<?php 

// config.php

return ["db" =>"mysql", "folder" => "cache"];

// index.php

$config = require_once("config.php");
```

In OOP it might look something like that. Do not have any validations!

```
<?php

    // path/to/config/file.php
    return ['db' => 'mysql'];

    // Config.php
    class Config
    {
        public static function getInstance($configFile) {
            if (self::$instance == null) {
                // check that file exists.

                $ext = strtolower(substr($configFile, -3));
                if ($ext === "php") {
                    $data = require($configFile);
                } elseif ($ext) === "ini") {
                    $data = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception('Can nod read config file');
                }

                self::$instance = new \ArrayObject($data, \ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
                //or
                //self::$instance = (object) $data;
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }

        private static $instance;
    }

    // Usage
    $config = Config::getInstance('path/to/config/file.php');
    echo $config->db;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, sorry I badly explained myself, I want to do that in a OO mode, I updated my question but what I want to do is to create a class that reads values from a config file, so when I create an instance of that class I have the config parameters as properties...

Comment: @user3174311 Added an example of how it can be used with OOP

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated it a little bit to also consider .json config files

Answer (score 0):

Most php config files use constants;

```
define("SITE_NAME", "My Test Site");
```

to read value;
    SITE_NAME